# How do the different AWS Failure-Handling Features for Kinesis and DynamoDB Event Sources interact?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

AWS has introduced [Failure-Handling Features for Kinesis and DynamoDB Event Sources](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/) as summarized below.

**Bisect on Function Error**
With Bisect on Function Error enabled, Lambda breaks the impacted batch of records into two when a function returns an error, and retries them separately. This allows you to easily separate the malformed data record from the rest of the batch, and process the rest of data records successfully.

**Maximum Record Age**
Your Lambda function can skip processing a data record when it has reached its Maximum Record Age, which can be configured from 60 seconds to 7 days.

**Maximum Retry Attempts**
Your Lambda function can skip retrying a batch of records when it has reached the Maximum Retry Attempts, which can be configured from 0 to 10,000.

I can't find any documentation on how these options interact. For example, if you configure bisect and also retry, does that mean it will retry each batch twice? Or not retry at all? Or not bisect?